# Java class as a function parameter using lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda

I have JUnit tests (which I cannot modify) and have to write a program in Java 8. The part of the tests that I'm interested in is:

```
Set<Customer> mexicans = shop.filter(Customer.class, c -> c.getCountry().equals("Mexico"));
Set<Product> goldenWaffles = shop.filter(Product.class, p -> p.getBrand().equals("Golden") && p.getName().contains("Waffles"));
```

So the second parameter of *filter* function is lambda expression, which I would take as parameter of type `Predicate<Product>` or `Predicate<Customer>` (am I right here?). The problem is: I need to be able to take them both and I don't know how to do it. Has it something to do with the first parameter?

Comment: What kind of object are you trying to filter?  Presumably a `Customer` can't be a golden waffle, and a `Product` can't be a Mexican; so what would it mean to apply both filters?

Comment: The filter method should be able to filter Customers and Products. It should probably decide what filtered set I want (Customers or Products) from the first parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are looking for something like

```
public <T> void method(Class<T> clazz, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    // ...
    final Set<T> result = shop.filter(clazz, predicate);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean for this to return `Set<T>` instead of `void`?

Comment: Depends on whether to work with the result of the method, or simply check for "not emptiness" or whatever.

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but `public Set<Product> filter(Class<Product> clazz, Predicate<Product> predicate)` and `public Set<Customer> filter(Class<Customer> clazz, Predicate<Customer> predicate)` creates same erasure error